# Настроить OpenVPN, OpenServer и VirtualBox на одном сервере

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, openserver, openvpn

Имеется статичный IP, установлен сервер (локальный IP 192.168.1.220) на базе Windows Server 2019, на котором под Open Server поднято веб-приложение - назовем его App1. В организации имеются удаленные филиалы, которые соединяются с сервером посредством OpenVPN для доступа к App1. На сервере также запущен виртуальный сервер Ubuntu в VirtualBox с другим локальным IP (192.168.1.199), на котором крутится еще одно приложение - App2. Все это прекрасно работает в одном сегменте сети, App2 доступен по IP. Задача состоит в том, чтобы организовать доступ к App2 из удаленных филиалов через существующее VPN-подключение. Перенос App2 в дополнительный домен Open Server нежелателен из-за разных требованиях к окружению (версий PHP, БД). Есть идеи? Спасибо!